# How to approve user_likes , facebook app?

Tags: facebook

i've tried a lot of times trying to do the approval on facebook for the user_likes permission, but without success  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYBy2.png), does anyone has any idea how to approve user_likes ?

Comment: They are not able to use your app so it has nothing to do with user_likes

Comment: What are you using the permission for?

Answer (score 0):

In your facebook app scope use "user_likes", I think it's work. Thanks